# jQuery Select Text from a Specific Row

Tags: jquery

With the following table:

```
<table id="languages" border="0" cellspacing="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Language</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Invented</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
</tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ruby</td>
      <td>Dynamic</td>
      <td>1993</td>
    </tr>    <table id="languages" border="0" cellspacing="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Language</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Invented</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Java</td>
          <td>Static</td>
          <td>1995</td>

    <tr>
      <td>Smalltalk</td>
      <td>Dynamic</td>
      <td>1972</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C++</td>
      <td>Static</td>
      <td>1983</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How would I select all the data from the third row? I would need to select Smalltalk, Dynamic, and 1971. The following selects the row. I need the data.

```
    #languages tr:eq(3)
```

Thanks

Comment: after opening first "<tbody>" you are closing </tr> which is not opened and using same id for multiple tables is not a good idea, this will not give you desired markup.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$('#languages tr:eq(3)').text()
```

to get the whole text

and

```
$('#languages tr:eq(3) td').map(function(){return $(this).text()}).toArray()
```

to get an array of the texts : `["Smalltalk", "Dynamic", "1972"]`

But note that your html has errors and that your row seems to be in `'#languages tr:eq(2)'`, not `'#languages tr:eq(3)'`.

[Demonstration (open the console)](http://jsfiddle.net/aBKbC/)

Answer (score 0):

Put not standard attribute to tr tag: `<tr key="1215">` where key s id in database table, then select row and cells: `$('[key=3]').find('td').each(...` Working sample http://jsbin.com/ofasin/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="languages" border="0" cellspacing="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Language</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Invented</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr key="1">
      <td>Ruby</td>
      <td>Dynamic</td>
      <td>1993</td>
    </tr>
    <tr key="2">
      <td>Java</td>
      <td>Static</td>
      <td>1995</td>
    </tr>
    <tr key="3">
      <td>Smalltalk</td>
      <td>Dynamic</td>
      <td>1972</td>
    </tr>
    <tr key="4">
      <td>C++</td>
      <td>Static</td>
      <td>1983</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>  
  <script>
    var row = new Array();
    $('[key=3]').find('td').each(function(){
      row.push($(this).text());
    });
    alert('' + row);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the replies. I am trying out some of the suggestions now. It looks like I made a mistake copying & pasting.